# Router navigation in Angular

Tags: angular

I am learning angular for this I have started Library management project. And now I have stuck at the point. Here is the detail. When Admin log in he has a display with sidebar and book display like this:
[Admin Home Page with dummy book Data. Route: http://localhost:4200/admin/(admin:home)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk1gn.png) I can navigate from
**admin homepage** to **profile page** and from **admin homepage** to **Users**.
But I cannot move from **profile page** to **Users** directly.
I'm using named router outlet as I have different user roles and want to show different screens based on roles.
**Routes**
Admin homepage: /admin/(admin:home)
Profile page: /profile/:email
Users: admin/(admin:list-users)

Please Note that I have to not nested profile route because it is generic for other users who have different roles as well.

I'm getting this error when I try to navigate from profile/:email to admin/users
(Here email is the dynamic variable)
**NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'profile/abc@gmail.com'**
Here is my code

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginGuardGuard } from './shared/guard/login-guard.guard';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(x => x.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sign-up/sign-up.module').then(x => x.SignUpModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/:email', component: SignUpComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuardGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'book/edit/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./book/book.module').then(x => x.BookModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'book/add',
    loadChildren: () => import('./book/book.module').then(x => x.BookModule)
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

admin-home-page-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginGuardGuard } from 'src/app/shared/guard/login-guard.guard';
import { BookListDisplayComponent } from '../shared/components/book-list-display/book-list-display.component';
import { AdminHomePageComponent } from './components/home-page/admin-home-page.component';
import { UsersListComponent } from './components/users-list/users-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin', canActivate: [LoginGuardGuard], component: AdminHomePageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home', component: BookListDisplayComponent, outlet: "admin",
      },
      {
        path: 'list-users', component: UsersListComponent, outlet: "admin"
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminHomePageRoutingModule { }
```

admin-home-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './admin-home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-home-page.component.css']
})
export class AdminHomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { admin: ['home'] } }], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute })
  }

}
```

admin-home-page.component.html

```
<admin-side-bar></admin-side-bar>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

admin-side-bar.component.html

```
<!-- version 1 -->

<nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo">
        <a [routerLink]="'summary'">
            <img src="../../../../assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li [routerLink]="['/profile',userEmail]" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'admin': ['list-users'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Users</a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLink]="['/admin/list-permissions']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Permissions</a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLink]="['/admin/books-issue-details']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Book Issue Summary</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried different approaches that i found during my search like I had modified my original side-bar code like this

```
<!-- version 2 -->

<nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo">
        <a [routerLink]="'summary'">
            <img src="../../../../assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li [routerLink]="['/profile',userEmail]" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLink]="['profile', userEmail,{ outlets: { 'admin': ['list-users'] } }]"
                routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Users</a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLink]="['/admin/list-permissions']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Permissions</a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLink]="['/admin/books-issue-details']" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a>Book Issue Summary</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But then I was not able to move from admin home page to Users directly. Error that i got that time was
**Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'**
I need guidance to solve this problem. I will be thankful.

Comment: Maybe you missed a '/' in the route: 'profile' -> '/profile' ?

Comment: @Pierre-HenriSudre in version 2 of side-bar?

Comment: @Pierre-HenriSudre I have added '/' in the route: 'profile' in version 2 and now I'm getting this error. Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'profile/abc@gmail.com'